# tooltip for WMS points with geoext

Tags: extjs, openlayers, geoserver, wms, geoext

My idea is to get tooltip contains information about the point ,
these points return from WMS layer, 
i tried these ways:

1- with vector layer there is "graphictitle" when styling the points and it display a tooltip,
but with WMS i could not find property to use it as a tooltip in SLD(wms styling).

2- when i use ext tooltip , its return wrong location because i don't know what the target .!

```
new Ext.ToolTip({
        target: 'no target',
        html: 'A very simple tooltip'       }).show();})
```

3- so i want to use geoext .

can any one help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how :)

by using:

```
showAt([e.xy.x,e.xy.y]);
```